Show that if $|w_1|, |w_2| < \frac{1}{2}$, then $|f(w_1) − f(w_2)| ≤ 4|w_1 − w_2|$
Suppose that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the disk $|z| < 2$, and $|f(z)| < 1$ for every $z$
such that $|z| < 1$.
Show that if $|w_1|, |w_2| < \frac{1}{2}$, then $|f(w_1) − f(w_2)| ≤ 4|w_1 − w_2|$.
I have no idea how to deal with this, I have heard something about Schwarz Lemma but I do not know, it can be used here or not, and how to use that if it works.
Thank you in advance.

apply Cauchy theorem on $|z|=1$ and note that $1/(z-w_1)-1/(z-w_2)=(w_1-w_2)/(z-w_1)(z-w_2)$ and the denominator is at least $1/4$ so $|1/(z-w_1)-1/(z-w_2)| \le 4|w_1-w_2|$ when $|z|=1$ etc

First, Thanks to "Conrad".
By applying Cauchy's Integral Formula to $|z| = 1 - \epsilon$, for
$0 < \epsilon < \frac{1}{2}$, we have:
$$
f(w_1) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=1-\epsilon} \frac{f(z)}{z-w_1} dz, \,
f(w_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=1-\epsilon} \frac{f(z)}{z-w_2} dz.
$$
Now for the difference,
$$
f(w_2) - f(w_1) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=1-\epsilon} \frac{f(z)}{z-w_2} - \frac{f(z)}{z-w_1} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=1-\epsilon} \frac{f(z)(w_2-w_1)}{(z-w_2)(z-w_1)} dz.
$$
So,
$$
|f(w_2) - f(w_1)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{|z|=1-\epsilon} |\frac{f(z)(w_2-w_1)}{(z-w_2)(z-w_1)}| dz \leq (1-\epsilon)|w_2-w_1|\sup_{|z|=1-\epsilon}(\frac{1}{(z-w_2)(z-w_1)}).
$$
and the desired bounding will be attained by letting
$\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ because,
$$
|z-w_2||z-w_1| \geq (|z|-|w_2|)(|z|-|w_1|) \geq (1-\epsilon-\frac{1}{2})(1-\epsilon-\frac{1}{2}) = (\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon)^2.
$$

so the hypothesis of homolorphicity up |z| < 2 has not been fully exploited. Am I right?

The Schwarz-Pick theorem (a variant of the Schwarz lemma) can be applied to $f$, that gives a better bound:
$$
\left| \frac{f(w_1) - f(w_2)}{1- \overline{f(w_1)} f(w_2)} \right| \le 
\left| \frac{w_1 - w_2}{1- \overline{w_1} w_2} \right| 
$$
implies
$$
|f(w_1) - f(w_2)| \le \frac 83 \cdot |w_1 - w_2|
$$
because
$$
 \frac{|1- \overline{f(w_1)} f(w_2)|}{|1- \overline{w_1} w_2|}
\le \frac{1 +| f(w_1)| \cdot | f(w_2)|}{1- |w_1 | \cdot | w_2|}
\le \frac{1 + 1}{1- 1/4} = \frac 83 \, .
$$
Note that it suffices to assume that $f$ is holomorphic in $|z| < 1$ with $|f(z)| < 1$ for $|z| < 1$.
